# Actualizar varios registros de una tabla con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Necesito actualizar múltiples registros en una tabla productos que posee los campos `id_producto` y `stock_actual`.

Le paso los array `codigo` y `total` por ajax y no me funciona, también envío 2 variables para otra actualización. El array `codigo` serían los `id` de cada valor del array total que debe actualizar el campo `stock_actual` con sus valores.

Adjunto el **script** de la función:

```
function generar() {
  var idproducto = document.getElementById("id-producto").value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("canti").value;
  var total =[]; 

  var codigo =[]; 

  $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    total.push($(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text());
    codigo.push($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text());

  });

  var totala = total;
  var codigoa = codigo;

  var dataString = {idproducto:idproducto,
      cantidad:cantidad,
      totala:totala,
      codigoa:codigoa}


      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "data/ejecutaentc.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            alertify.alert("Atención","Cantidad agregada: "+totala);
        }
    });

  }
```

el archivo php donde van los datos de ajax:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    require_once "conexion.php";

    $idproducto = $_POST['idproducto'];

    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $total = $_POST['totala'];

    //$foo = array($total);

    $codigo = $_POST['codigoa'];
    //$codigo = json_decode($_POST['codigo']);
    //$fooc = array($codigo);
    //var_dump($codigo);
    var_dump($_POST['codigoa']);
    $icodigo = count($codigo);
    $itotal = count($total);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $icodigo && $i < $itotal; $i++) {

        $sentencia1 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual ='$total' where id_producto= '$codigo'";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia1);

    }

    $sentencia2 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual = stock_actual+'$cantidad' where id_producto= '$idproducto'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia2);

    ?>
```

Agrego imagen de la tabla de donde extraigo los datos y el input:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

parte del código html desde el botón Generar entrada:

```
<?php

extract($_GET);

$sql = "SELECT productos.id_producto, productos.name, productos.marca, productos.modelo,  productos.stock_actual,  productos.precio_compra, productos.precio_unidad,  categorias.name, media.file_name, productos.fecha_ingreso, productos.proveedor,  productos.nro_expediente,   productos.desc_prod, productos.id_categoria, productos.id_media FROM productos, categorias, media WHERE productos.id_producto = '$id' and productos.id_categoria= categorias.id_categoria and productos.id_media= media.id_media";

$ressql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($ressql)) {
    $id = $row[0];
    $name = $row[1];
    $marca = $row[2];
    $modelo = $row[3];
    $stock_actual = $row[4];

    $precio_compra = $row[5];
    $precio_unidad = $row[6];
    $id_categoria = $row[7];
    $id_media = $row[8];
    $fecha_ingreso = date_create($row[9]);
    $proveedor = $row[10];
    $nro_expediente = $row[11];
    $desc_prod = $row[12];
    $id_cat1 = $row[13];
    $id_med1 = $row[14];
}

?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-title">
      <div>
        <h1><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>Entrada de Productos Compuestos</h1>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-9 ">
    <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 390px">
      <div class="card-title-w-btn">
        <h3 class="title">Detalle de Producto</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" action="data/ejecutaent.php">

            <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-area" id="id-area" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_area)) {
                    echo $id_area;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">IDusuario:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-user" id="id-user" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_user)) {
                    echo $id_user;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-producto" id="id-producto" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id)) {
                    echo $id;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <label class="control-label">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-name" id="product-name" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($name)) {
                    echo $name;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Marca:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-marca" id="product-marca" placeholder="Marca" value="<?php if (isset($marca)) {
                    echo $marca;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <label class="control-label">Modelo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-modelo" id="product-modelo" placeholder="Modelo" value="<?php if (isset($modelo)) {
                    echo $modelo;
                }
                ?>"  readonly>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Proveedor:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="15" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" placeholder="Proveedor" value="<?php if (isset($proveedor)) {
                    echo $proveedor;
                }
                ?>" readonly >
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
               <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
               <input type="text" maxlength="14"class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" placeholder="Expediente" value="<?php if (isset($nro_expediente)) {
                echo $nro_expediente;
            }
            ?>" readonly >
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">

          <label class="control-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
          <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local"      class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fechain" id="fechain" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo $fecha_ingreso->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') ?>"  readonly>

          </div>


          <div class="col-md-4">

              <label class="control-label">Fecha de Entrada</label>
              <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local"      class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fecha-in" id="fecha-in" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo $hoy3->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') ?>"readonly>

          </div>




          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label">Cantidad en depósito:</label>
            <div class="input-group">

             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
             <input type="number"  min="1" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ini" id="cantidad_ini" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?php if (isset($stock_actual)) {
                echo $stock_actual;
            }
            ?>" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Cantidad ingresada:</label>
                <div class="input-group">

                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
                 <input type="number"   min="0.00" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ent" id="cantidad_ent" placeholder="Cantidad" value="" >
             </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none;" >
                <label class="control-label">Precio x Unidad:</label>
                <div class="input-group">

                 <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                 <input type="number"  max="99999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_unidad" id="precio_unidad" placeholder="Precio x unidad" value="<?php if (isset($precio_unidad)) {echo $precio_unidad;}?>">
             </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none;" >
                <label class="control-label">Precio total:</label>
                <div class="input-group">

                 <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                 <input type="number"  max="9999999999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_compra" id="precio_compra" placeholder="Precio total" value="<?php if (isset($precio_compra)) {echo $precio_compra;}?>">
             </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-4 ">
               <label class="control-label">Nº de Remito</label>
               <input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9--]/g,'');"  maxlength="15" class="form-control" name="remito" id="remito" placeholder="Remito" value="<?php echo '0000' . '-' . $id ?>" required readonly >
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 ">
               <label class="control-label">Receptor:</label>
               <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="receptor-ent" id="receptor-ent" placeholder="Receptor" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" required readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
               <label class="control-label">Observaciones:</label>
               <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="obs_ent" id="obs_ent" placeholder="Oservación" value="" >
            </div>
            <h2></h2>

            <div class="col-md-10" >

                <h2></h2>

                <a  href="adm_prodc.php" id="vlistado" name="vlistado" class="btn btn-info">Volver al Listado</a>
                <button  type="button" onclick="abreModal()"class="btn btn-info"   > <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Detalle de productos</button>

                <button type="button" onclick="generar()" value="Generar producto" id="add_prod" name="add_prod" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Generar Entrada</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 390px">
      <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
      <p><img src='<?php echo "uploads/$id_media" ?>' class='img-thumbnail'></p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

        <div id="resultados1" class="table-container"  style="display:none; "><!-- Carga los datos ajax

           Modal Busca Producto-->


           <h4>Detalle de productos que integran el <?php echo $name ?> </h4>
           <h2></h2>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               <label >Cantidad ingresada:</label>
               <input name="canti" id="canti" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(1, this.maxLength);"
               type = "number"
               maxlength = "4"
               min="1">
           </div>
           <h3></h3>
           <button  type="button"  id="calculo" name="calculo" onclick="asignar()"class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 25px;"  > <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Asignar cantidad</button>
           <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>
           <style>
               .table-container {
                height: 30em;
            }
            table {
              table-layout: fixed;
              display: flex;
              flex-flow: column;
              height: 300px;
              width: 100%;
          }
          table thead {
            /* head takes the height it requires,
            and it's not scaled when table is resized */
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
        }
        table tbody {
            /* body takes all the remaining available space */
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: block;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        table tbody tr {
            width: 100%;
        }
        table thead,
        table tbody tr {
            display: table;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        /* decorations */
        .table-container {
            /*border: 1px solid black;*/
            padding: 0.3em;
            min-width: 100%;

        }
        .codigo {
          width: 10%;

          text-align: center;


      }
      .producto {
          width: 15%;

          text-align: center;


      }
      .modelo {
          width: 15%;

          text-align: center;


      }
      .expediente {
          width: 20%;

          text-align: center;


      }
      .stock {
          width: 15%;

          text-align: center;


      }
      .cantidad {
          width: 15%;
          text-align: center;

      }
      .total {
          width: 15%;

          text-align: center;

      }
      .red{
        background: #654DAF  !important;
        color: #fff;
    }
    table {
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }
    table td, table th {
        padding: 0.3em;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    table th {
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
</style>

<?php
require_once 'data/conexion.php';

$sql = "SELECT producto_comp.id_producto as idcomp, productos.name as name, productos.modelo as modelo,  productos.nro_expediente as expediente, productos.stock_actual as stockactual, producto_comp.cantidad_producto as cantidad  from producto_comp, productos where  producto_comp.codigopc = '$id' and  productos.id_producto = producto_comp.id_producto  and producto_comp.id_area = '$id_area' and producto_comp.codigopc NOT IN (0) order by productos.name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<table  class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th class="codigo" >Código</th>

            <th class="producto">Producto</th>
            <th class="modelo">Modelo</th>
            <th class="expediente" >Expediente</th>

            <th  class="stock"> Stock actual </th>
            <th class="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
            <th class="total">Stock restante</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?> <tr><?php
            $codigo = $row['idcomp'];
            $producto = $row['name'];
            $modelo = $row['modelo'];
            $expediente = $row['expediente'];
            $stock = $row['stockactual'];
            $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

            ?>

            <td class='codigo' ><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
            <td class="producto" ><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
            <td class="modelo" ><?php echo $modelo; ?></td>
            <td class="expediente"><?php echo $expediente; ?></td>
            <td class="stock"  ><?php echo $stock; ?></td>
            <td class="cantidad"><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
            <td class="total" ></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>

</table>

</div>

</div>

</body>

<?php

require_once 'static/footer.php'

?>
```

Imagen de como muestra el array totala en success:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En `var datos` quita las comillas a las propiedades del objeto para que quede algo como: `var datos = { total :total, codigo: codigo, idproducto: idproducto, cantidad: cantidad }`. Por otra parte, si nos explicases un poco más el error que te ocurre podríamos saber en donde te pasa, desgraciadamente un "no funciona" no suele dar muchas pistas al respecto.

Comment: No funciona, me parece que el error esta en como envia los datos... creo

Comment: ¿En el **PHP** has hecho un `echo` de las variables en las que almacenas los datos que te llegan desde `$_POST` para comprobar si es en ese punto donde tienes el problema?

Comment: agrege echo '<script>alert("ENTRADA de productos ya realizada"+codigo.join('=')+total.join(', ')); </script>'; despues de los $_POST en php y no devuelve nada

Comment: me funciono cambiando  dataType: "html", en el ajax y actualiza la sentencia2 pero no actualiza en la sentencia1 dentro del bucle for..

Comment: Perdón alguna idea, no puedo envíar los arrays al archivo php

Answer (score 1):

Estas son algunas observaciones sobre el código, e indicaciones de como podrías realizar resolver ciertos problemas.

Para los estilos, no hace falta que agregues `display: none;` a todos los elementos del formulario para ocultar cada uno, basta con agregar una clase en el div contenedor para que se oculte todo.

Para eso puedes usar la clase `d-none` de bootstrap o asignar por id en la sección de css:

En el input de cantidad ingresada al ser de tipo `number` no funciona colocarle la propiedad `maxlenght`, para evitar números con tamaño mayor a 4 puedes colocarle `max=9999`, luego te recomiendo dejarle un valor por defecto (1):

```
<input name="canti" id="canti" class="form-control" type = "number" max = 9999 value=1 min="1">
```

Para tus consultas SQL puedes agregarles un alias a las tablas y colocar saltos de linea  para que sean mas entendibles:

```
$sql = "SELECT P.id_producto, P.name, P.marca, P.modelo,  
  P.stock_actual,  P.precio_compra, P.precio_unidad,  C.name, 
  M.file_name, P.fecha_ingreso, P.proveedor,  P.nro_expediente,   
  P.desc_prod, P.id_categoria, P.id_media 
  FROM productos P, categorias C, media M
  WHERE P.id_producto = '$id' and P.id_categoria= C.id_categoria 
  and P.id_media = M.id_media";
```

En mysqli si la consulta solo retorna una fila, no hace falta que recorras el resultado con un `while`, basta usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
$ressql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ressql);
```

de esa forma también puedes referenciar un campo solo con su nombre en la consulta (es mejor que por el numero de columna) y puedes agregarlo directamente a los campos:

```
<div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
     <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" maxlength="18" name="id-producto" id="id-producto" placeholder="Nombre" readonly>
</div>
```

Luego en el código para enviar los datos por ajax, en lugar de tener 2 arrays con los códigos y totales de los productos, puedes tener un array de objetos, cada objeto con su respectivo código y total para enviarlos en una variable:

```
function generar() {

    var idproducto = document.getElementById("id-producto").value;
    var cantidad = document.getElementById("canti").value;

    var elementos = [];

    $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
      var ele = {
        codigo : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        total : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
      }
      elementos.push(ele);
    });

    var dataString = {
      idproducto : idproducto,
      cantidad : cantidad,
      elementos : elementos
    }
    // console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "data/ejecutaentc.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
        alertify.alert("Atención","Cantidad agregada: "+cantidad);
      }
    });
  }
```

En el archivo php en el que recibes los datos, en lugar de recorrer el resultado con un `for` puedes usar un `foreach`, de esa forma no tienes que calcular antes el tamaño:

```
<?php
  //archivo php donde van los datos de ajax
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
  require_once "conexion.php";

  $idproducto = $_POST['idproducto'];

  $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];

  $elementos = $_POST['elementos'];

  foreach ($elementos as $value) {

    $sentencia1 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual ='$value[total]' where id_producto= '$value[codigo]'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia1);

  }

  $sentencia2 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual = stock_actual+'$cantidad' where id_producto= '$idproducto'";

  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia2);

?>
```

y el resto del código te quedaría así:

```
<?php

  extract($_GET);

  $sql = "SELECT P.id_producto, P.name, P.marca, P.modelo,  
  P.stock_actual,  P.precio_compra, P.precio_unidad,  C.name, 
  M.file_name, P.fecha_ingreso, P.proveedor,  P.nro_expediente,   
  P.desc_prod, P.id_categoria, P.id_media 
  FROM productos P, categorias C, media M
  WHERE P.id_producto = '$id' and P.id_categoria= C.id_categoria 
  and P.id_media = M.id_media";

  $ressql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($ressql));

?>

<style>
  #calculo{
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  #card1{
    background-color: #F9F8F5; 
    height: 390px
  }
  .table-container {
    height: 30em;
  }
  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  table thead {
    /* head takes the height it requires,
    and it's not scaled when table is resized */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
  }
  table tbody {
    /* body takes all the remaining available space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  table tbody tr {
    width: 100%;
  }
  table thead,
  table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  /* decorations */
  .table-container {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    padding: 0.3em;
    min-width: 100%;

  }
  .codigo {
    width: 10%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .producto {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .modelo {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .expediente {
    width: 20%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .stock {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .cantidad {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .total {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: center;


  }
  .red{
    background: #654DAF  !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  }
  table td, table th {
    padding: 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  table th {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
</style>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="page-title">
    <div>
      <h1><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>Entrada de Productos Compuestos</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-9 ">
      <div class="card" id="card1" >
        <div class="card-title-w-btn">
          <h3 class="title">Detalle de Producto</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form method="post" action="data/ejecutaent.php">

            <div class="col-md-4 " style="">
              <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-area" id="id-area" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_area)) {
                echo $id_area;
              }
              ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 " >
              <label class="control-label">IDusuario:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-user" id="id-user" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_user)) {
                echo $id_user;
              }
              ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 " >
              <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-producto" id="id-producto" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
              <label class="control-label">Nombre:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-name" id="product-name" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="control-label">Marca:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-marca" id="product-marca" placeholder="Marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca'] ?>"  readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
              <label class="control-label">Modelo:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-modelo" id="product-modelo" placeholder="Modelo" value="<?php echo $row['modelo'] ?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="control-label">Proveedor:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="15" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" placeholder="Proveedor" value="<?php echo $row['proveedor'] ?>" readonly >
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
             <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
             <input type="text" maxlength="14"class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" placeholder="Expediente" value="<?php echo $row['nro_expediente'] ?>" readonly >
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
            <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fechain" id="fechain" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime($row['fecha_ingreso'])) ?>" readonly>
           </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="control-label">Fecha de Entrada</label>
              <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fecha-in" id="fecha-in" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo $hoy3->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') ?>"readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="control-label">Cantidad en depósito:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
               <input type="number"  min="1" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ini" id="cantidad_ini" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?php echo $row['stock_actual'] ?>" readonly>
             </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="control-label">Cantidad ingresada:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
               <input type="number" min="0.00" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ent" id="cantidad_ent" placeholder="Cantidad" value="1" >
             </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4" >
            <label class="control-label">Precio x Unidad:</label>
            <div class="input-group">

             <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
             <input type="number"  max="99999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_unidad" id="precio_unidad" placeholder="Precio x unidad" value="<?php echo $row['precio_unidad'] ?>">
             </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4" >
            <label class="control-label">Precio total:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
             <input type="number"  max="9999999999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_compra" id="precio_compra" placeholder="Precio total" value="<?php echo $row['precio_compra'] ?>">
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 ">
             <label class="control-label">Nº de Remito</label>
             <input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9--]/g,'');"  maxlength="15" class="form-control" name="remito" id="remito" placeholder="Remito" value="<?php echo '0000' . '-' . $row['id_producto'] ?>" required readonly >
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 ">
             <label class="control-label">Receptor:</label>
             <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="receptor-ent" id="receptor-ent" placeholder="Receptor" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" required readonly>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
             <label class="control-label">Observaciones:</label>
             <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="obs_ent" id="obs_ent" placeholder="Oservación" value="" >
           </div>
           <h2></h2>

           <div class="col-md-10" >

            <h2></h2>

            <a href="adm_prodc.php" id="vlistado" name="vlistado" class="btn btn-info">Volver al Listado</a>
            <button  type="button" onclick="abreModal()"class="btn btn-info"   > <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Detalle de productos</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="generar()" value="Generar producto" id="add_prod" name="add_prod" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Generar Entrada</button>

          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card1" >
          <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
          <p><img src='<?php echo "uploads/$row[id_media]" ?>' class='img-thumbnail'></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="resultados1" class="table-container" >
    <!-- Carga los datos ajax Modal Busca Producto-->
      <h4>Detalle de productos que integran el <?php echo $name ?> </h4>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label >Cantidad ingresada:</label>
        <input name="canti" id="canti" class="form-control" type = "number" max = 9999 value=1 min="1">
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="calculo" name="calculo" onclick="asignar()" class="btn btn-info" > 
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Asignar cantidad
      </button>
      <br>

    <?php

    require_once 'data/conexion.php';

    $sql = "SELECT C.id_producto as idcomp, P.name as name, P.modelo as modelo,  
    P.nro_expediente as expediente, P.stock_actual as stockactual, 
    C.cantidad_producto as cantidad  
    from producto_comp C, productos P
    where C.codigopc = '$id' and  P.id_producto = C.id_producto  
    and C.id_area = '$id_area' and C.codigopc NOT IN (0) 
    order by P.name";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>

    <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="codigo" >Código</th>
          <th class="producto">Producto</th>
          <th class="modelo">Modelo</th>
          <th class="expediente" >Expediente</th>
          <th class="stock"> Stock actual </th>
          <th class="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
          <th class="total">Stock restante</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?> 
          <tr>
            <td class='codigo' ><?php echo $row['idcomp'] ?></td>
            <td class="producto" ><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td class="modelo" ><?php echo $row['modelo']; ?></td>
            <td class="expediente"><?php echo $row['expediente']; ?></td>
            <td class="stock"  ><?php echo $row['stockactual']; ?></td>
            <td class="cantidad"><?php echo $row['cantidad']; ?></td>
            <td class="total" ></td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
  </div>
</div>

</body>

<?php

require_once 'static/footer.php'

?>
```

Esas son las observaciones que puedo dar de momento.

Comment: Gracias The-breaker lo reviso ahora mismo y te cuento los resultados...Muchas Gracias...